# what are the best ways to generate pdf file of the reactjs application's page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a react app in which there is a component which contains a table and that table consist of 25-30 columns which is not possible to show completely in a normal size screen, if i use the print button of the browser (**ctrl + P**)<-- `shortcut key` then it will not print the entire table.So that's why it is required to add button to create a pdf file of the entire table. What are the best ways to generate the pdf of for the applications which also covers large volume of data flowing to x-axis of the screen
[image: starting table]

[image: Proceeding table]

React hooks is preferable because the application is full functional and ready to deploy

Comment: It is recommended to configure the screen to fit the print paper size, such as A4 or A3. Try deleting columns with no data or reducing padding and margin values. :)